# GTA 5 No more missions!

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

OK so I completed the Special Bonds things I think because I did the last one. I talked with Maude and she and Trevor said Goodbye, and I went back to the city. But now, I do not seem any of the Story Mode Missions showing up! So I cannot do the rest of the missions to unlock the rest of the characters again! Please help! Also I have already completed the Mr. Phillips Thing. (This is NOT online mode).
Thanks,
Zjump!

Answer (score 2):

1. Switch to Franklin.
2. Call Tanya and do last job with car.
3. Then go with Michael at home and go to sleep.
4. He´ll wake up and you´ll see next mission with Lester.....

Comment: I cannot access Micheal nor Franklin since they are both not unlocked yet! I am only at 20 Percent!!!!